# Unable to set up interceptor/brokerplugin in ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

I have written a simple authentication/authorization plugin that I want to inject into ActiveMQ.  I want it to be called onConnect and onSubscribe.  I have followed [these steps at the ActiveMQ website](http://activemq.apache.org/interceptors.html) but a couple of things happen.

1) If I put in my bean declaration in the default activemq.xml file in //beans/broker/plugins I get a validation error saying that the node "bean" is not allowed there.

2) If I put the plugin declaration outside of the broker element it will inject the element, but it will not call installPlugin() nor the hooks, presumably because that is for the broker to do.

3) If I change the XML namespace declaration in the default activemq.xml (http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core) to that which is stated in the docs listed above (http://activemq.org/config/1.0) along with the proper URLs, I get the error that it cannot find the schema document.

The only thing I can come up with is that either there were changes in 5.6 that were not reflected in the documentation, I'm doing something very wrong, or I'm just crazy.  Here is the relevant portion of the xml doc (minus several nodes not directly related to the problem).

```
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:amq="http://activemq.org/config/1.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">

  <plugins>
     <bean id="tokenLoginPlugin" class="auth.TokenLoginPlugin">
       <property name="host" value="localhost" />
     </bean>
   </plugins>
</broker>
```

This generates the following exception.

```
The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'broker'.
```

If I use the xmlns declarations from the default activemq.xml file, I get the following.

```
Invalid content was found starting with element 'bean'
```

I can see that it's a validation error, but none of the docs seem to be pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out, though I had tried it before and it hadn't worked.  Perhaps I had messed up my namespaces the last time.  I changed my plugin definition and added the Spring namespace to my bean declaration.

```
<plugins>
    <bean id="tokenLoginPlugin" class="auth.TokenLoginPlugin" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
        <property name="host" value="localhost" />
    </bean>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

My configuration is :

```
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

<plugins>
     <bean  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  id="probePlugin" class="com.ProbePlugin"/>
</plugins>


</beans>
```